# Android - Cannot setClickable(false) a button after click

Tags: java, android, button, clickable

I have a button like a switch where I am trying to **setClickable(false)** after I click it so that only the first click will be handled
(additional clicks are ignored in the case of accidental double-clicks/multiple-clicks).

Here is a similar code:

```
Button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Button.setClickable(false);
        //do other things
    }
});
```

Then eventually, I have a code somewhere where I will reset the clickable to true, depending on a state variable, so I can switch-off.

The problem is when I click the button very quickly, it seems the succeeding clicks are still handled.
Is there a delay to the effects of setClickable()?

Also, I have read about using setEnabled(false) instead, but I cannot use it in my case. I need the button to still be enabled but not clickable.

Comment: After you done do the other things, you can enable back the Button

Comment: You can try **setVisibility** to **GONE**

Answer (score 1):

Judging from your comment you probably need something like this.

```
  Boolean SWITCH_ON = false;

  Button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
 
  public void onClick(View v) {
         if(!SWITCH_ON ){
                  SWITCH_ON = true;   
         }
    }
 });

Button.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {

public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
    
   if(SWITCH_ON ){
      // do your task for long click here ...SWITCH_ON 
    }
   return true;
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `button.setEnabled(false);` within your `onClick` method to disable the button.

Disabled buttons don't trigger the `onClick` method, and you can easily re-enable it with `button.setEnabled(true);` when needed.

Comment: I cannot disable the button. I need the button to still be enabled, but not clickable. The reason, which I did not state yet, is that the button needs to be long-clickable when the switch is ON.

Answer (score 0):

You could add another variable named *buttonEnabled* or so and initialize it with *true*. Then in the onclick do this:

```java
Button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Button.setClickable(false);
        if(buttonEnabled) {
            //do other things
        }
        buttonEnabled = false;
    }
});
```

Note that you need to change the variable to if you want to reactivate it